# Semi join sub-selects are only allowed at the top level WHERE expressions and not in nested WHERE expressions

Tags: apex, soql, query, exception

I am currently facing an issue while trying to update the criteria of a SOQL query and was wondering if anyone could help me out.

To provide some context: I am building an automation to propagate information which is retrieved from a backend endpoint and propagate it onto existing Accounts on Salesforce. These Accounts relate to the information returned by the backend by either a Customer Id, a Phone, or an E-mail.

Originally I was trying to retrieve **Accounts that relate to one of the Set of strings provided** (customerIds, phoneNumbers, and emails) **AND have related Cases**) and was able to do so with the following query:

```
return new List<Account>(
            [
                SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, PersonEmail, Customer_Id__c
                FROM Account
                WHERE
                    IsPersonAccount = TRUE
                    AND (Customer_Id__c IN :customerIds
                    OR PersonEmail IN :emailAddresses
                    OR Phone IN :phoneNumbers)
                    AND ID IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case)
            ]
        );
```

However, due to some requirement updates, I want to update my query so that I retrieve **Accounts that relate by Customer_Id__c without taking into consideration if they have or not related cases**) and **Accounts that relate by Phone or Email AND have related Cases).**

I updated my original query to the following one:

```
return new List<Account>(
        [
            SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, PersonEmail, Customer_Id__c
            FROM Account
            WHERE
                Customer_Id__c IN :customerIds
                OR
                ((PersonEmail IN :emailAddresses
                OR Phone IN :phoneNumbers) AND ID IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case)
                )
```

but started running against a `Semi join sub-selects are only allowed at the top level WHERE expressions and not in nested WHERE expressions` exception.

Am I able to retrieve this information using only one query in some other way? Or will I have to split the logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just split it out into separate queries rather than trying to fit all this logic in one. Your `Customer Id` logic doesn't need the join at all, so that is what I would split out. Depending on your org architecture and data volume, you may want to split out a third query to avoid `OR` logic altogether.

```
Map<Id, Account> records = new Map<Id, Account>([
    SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE Customer_Id__c IN :customerIds
]);
records.putAll([
    SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE PersonEmail IN :emailAddressess
    AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case)
]);
records.putAll([
    SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE Phone IN :phoneNumbers
    AND Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case)
]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this is what I had before and ended up doing (splitting the logic between Customer Id and Phone/Email). However it leads me into some doubts on where to draw the line between following "best practices" (as in trying to use the minimal number of queries per transaction) or going with a different approach.

Comment: If you are in a UI layer, number of queries likely doesn't matter. If you are in the domain layer, minimizing them is vital. That said, avoiding `OR` evaluations in your queries is pretty important in orgs with large data volume. And this logic seems like it belongs to a UI, though you didn't share that context information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'simplify' your boolean logic.  I have used the following site for years...  https://www.dcode.fr/boolean-expressions-calculator.  Your boolean updates to the following format

```
a || ((b || c) and d) ==> a || (b && d) || (c && d)
```

Here is the SOQL Query

```
[
    SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Phone, PersonEmail, Customer_Id__c
    FROM Account
    WHERE
        Customer_Id__c IN :customerIds
        OR
        (PersonEmail IN :emailAddresses AND ID IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case))
        OR
        (Phone IN :phoneNumbers AND ID IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case))
]
```

In VSCode, SF static code analyzer reports your query has issues (as you said), but the static code analyzer does not report any errors for my code.

I would still check in your instance the costs of the above vs breaking out the logic into two queries.   I think breaking your logic into two queries will read better... and when it needs to be modified again will be less error-prone.

Comment: So thank you for the downvote.  :-/

Did you try running my code and the error appears in runtime?  If it does, you need to split the logic up, which again is cleaner code.

I also looked at moving the original FROM to Case, but that leads to other issues and even less readable code.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi @dbwood3. I downvoted your answer as the solution you provided does not compile, thus not being very useful. Additionally, I appreciate the suggestion to check in the costs but that also does not answer directly my question. I do not mind going with that approach but what I really want to understand is if there is the possibility to do it using one single query.

Comment: Hi User.  you send a code snippet (look at your update) that isn't compilable.
I simply rearranged your WHERE clause...

a || ((b || c) and d) ==> a || (b && d) || (c && d)

ps, I added the ';' to make it a full statement.  If it doesn't compile because of something to do with your org.  That seems pretty harsh.

Comment: Doing multiple joins against the same relationship is inefficient and may not even be supported.

Comment: @dbwood3 I believe that would be a different discussion, but agree with you that it might be considered a little harsh to downvote it since the original code was not compiling at all, thus I removed the downvote. Apologies for that and thanks again for the help.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I totally agree... the point of my answer is to satisfy the request of one query.  I would split it up.